# Why is Observable within Observable hanging?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an `http.get` call in my service `member.service.ts` and I want to wait until that call completes before proceeding in `app.component`, so I'm trying to wrap the `http.get` call into an Observable for processing in `app.component`.

[Note: previously, before I wrapped the service in an Observable, the service was working fine . . . the `http.get` call on its own works as expected and returns a JSON object.]

But when I wrapped the `http.get` call in an Observable, as below, the application hangs. I searched online and read about `flatMap`, `forkjoin`, etc., but I'd like to keep the current structure, where the `http.get` call is in the `member` service, and all the other code is in `app.component`.

Many thanks if any ideas why it's hanging and how to fix!

`member.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, from, of } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MemberService {
  url: string = "http://localhost:3000/sign-up";
  data: string = '';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getMemberForm(): Observable<any> {

   let library = this.http.get(this.url,{responseType: 'json'});

    library.subscribe((data) => {
      this.data = JSON.stringify(data);
    });
    return of(this.data);
  }

}
```

`app.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MemberService } from './member.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

@Injectable()
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  got_data: boolean = false;
  data: string;

  constructor(private member: MemberService) {}

  ngOnInit() {

    this.member.getMemberForm().subscribe((data)=>{
      this.data = data;
      if (this.data.length > 0) this.got_data = true; 
    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not handling the asynchrous code in a proper way.

**Asynchronous** code is the code which runs outside the normal execution flow of code. The code inside your `subscribe` method is asynchronous and it will only run when the response of HTTP call is received.

Change your code like this:

```
getMemberForm(): Observable<any> {

   return this.http.get(this.url,{responseType: 'json'})
    .pipe(map( res => of(JSON.stringify(res))))    
  }
```

You application is hanging probably because your `this.data` is undefined and your are trying to change `undefined` into `Observable`

Comment: Thank you! That works (but as below, I think no need for the `of()` call).

Answer (score 1):

Never subscribe in a service this is a "anti pattern" in reactive programming (rxjs), just create the observable(http call) in the service and than subscribe in you component to trigger the http request, {responseType: 'json'} isn't needed all the "latest" versions (>4.3) of angular http client do it by default

```
interface MyDataType{
    data: any;
}

 getMemberForm() {
   //no need to type the function return beacuse typescript will do it for you
   //you can type directly the http call
   return this.http.get<MyDataType>(this.url);

  }
```